# Calling AJAX will not post Letters only Numbers

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I am creating a single page application. I am using ajax to set coldfusion session variables. I have two separate buttons that call: the first is the "New Button" and the second is the "Print Labels Button" They both will post numbers if you enter them. But for the "New Button" I want it to accept Letters or Numbers when posting. Is there a way to return letters as well with ajax? I would think it should allow it since it is just taking the form.variable and creating a variable? I do not understand why it will not allow letters though.

http://jsfiddle.net/1zka4soy/16/

If you click on the print labels button and enter a number you will see the ajax call and what it sets on the alert. The New button is set up exactly the same but for some reason they both do not allow letters only numbers.

Is this an ajax rule that only lets you run numbers?

**CF: NewDealerSession.cfm**

```
<cfset session.dealerwork.newdealername = form.NewDealerName >
    <cfoutput> #session.dealerwork.newdealername# </Cfoutput>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".label_accept").click(function () {
        $('#LabelMaker').modal('hide');

    });

    $('#labelForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "index_proxy.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
            data: $('#labelForm').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data !== "") {     
                    var link = "DealerLabels.cfm";
                    window.open(link,'newStuff'); 
                }
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

    $(".dealer_accept").click(function(){
        $('#NewDealer').modal('hide');

    });

    $('#addDealer').on('submit', function (e) {
        alert("working");
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "proxy/NewDealerSession.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
            data: $('#addDealer').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Error**
When typing a "letter name"
    SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

No error if you enter a number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your coldfusion template is returning the session value directly, which results in invalid json when the value is a string because with JSON, strings must be wrapped in double quotes. Here's what it should look like when returning json:

```
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(session.dealerwork.newdealername)#</cfoutput>
```

That said, I've never had coldfusion generate a JSON string that wasn't an array or a struct, so I don't know if it will accept it. Usually json responses look more like this:

```
<cfset myResult = structNew()>
<cfset myResult.newDealerName = session.dealerwork.newdealername>
<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(myResult)#</cfoutput>
```

Depending on your version of coldfusion and your configuration, it may or may not keep the case on the struct name in the json. you'll have to figure that part out yourself. It'l either be `{"NEWDEALERNAME":"somevalue"}` or `{"newDealerName":"somevalue"}`

In this case it'd likely be easer to just change `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "text"`.

Comment: Yep.  Bottom line if jQuery is expecting to receive JSON, well ... the CF code needs to actually *return* JSON.  The original code is not doing that. You need to adjust the code to either a) return JSON or b) change the dataType to reflect what type of data is being returned - as KevinB mentioned.

Comment: look at it this way. If you wanted to return three different variables to the client, doing that as plain text is not going to be very easy, where as with json it's as simple as creating a struct or array. That and the fact that JSON can support complex data structures such as arrays and structs.